Auth0 doesnt work on Expo CLI development
I've tried the whole week to make Auth0 work with my Expo CLI development (not Expo GO).
I followed the exact documentation of Auth0 + Expo, i did everything right but for some reason when i reach the code line: await authorize(); it doesnt do anything,
i do reach the console logs of "here + here1 + after".
in my Auth0 Dashboard everything matches perfectly, including the callbackUrl...
this is my code, please if anyone can help me work my auth0 correct, or if you have ANY alternative for SSO like Auth0 for my Expo app, i will really appreciate that!
app / index.tsx:
import { useAuth0, Auth0Provider } from "react-native-auth0";
import { LoginScreen, WelcomeScreen } from "./screens";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Index() {
  const domain = "secret-shirley";
  const clientId = "secret-shirley-id";

  const { user, getCredentials } = useAuth0();
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUserLoggedIn = async () => {
      try {
        const credentials = await getCredentials();
        setIsAuthenticated(credentials?.accessToken ? true : false);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };

    checkUserLoggedIn();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <Auth0Provider domain={domain} clientId={clientId}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
}

app/screens/login/index.tsx:
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useAuth0 } from "react-native-auth0";

export const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { authorize } = useAuth0();

  const onPress = async () => {
    console.log("here");
    try {
      console.log("here1");
      await authorize();
      console.log('after')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Welcome! you are not logged in! Please log in to continue.</Text>
      <Button onPress={onPress} title="Log in" />
    </View>
  );
}; 

app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "meow",
    "slug": "meow",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.shirley.meow"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.shirley.meow"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      [
        "react-native-auth0",
        {
          "domain": "secret-shirley-id"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "6aee382c-e618-4ca8-acd7-87e994c82418"
      }
    }
  }
}

what am i doing wrong?
